# How to change Ajax forms transition in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, mobile, transition

Is there a way to change the transition of the Ajax forms in jQuery mobile ? For now, when I submit a form, if the validation (server-side) is successful, it slides to the « success page », that's ok but if the form is invalid, it slides to the same form with fields errors… It's kinda weird :) I'd like to make it fade instead…

I know I can override ajax submission but it's better with, though…

*** Edit ***

I found that we can override the default transition type, so I think I could make it with the default transiton set to 'fade' and specify the transition for the other links but it does't work, here is the code, not sure what's wrong…

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/mobile/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
```

in *custom.js*

```
$(document).live("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.defaultTransition: 'fade'
});
```

No error, nor 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly you can add the `data-transition` attribute to the form tag, like this:

```
<form method="post" data-transition="fade" action="/awesomeness">
  ...
```

But I have yet to see it work effectively.

### FIXED

Well, I've submitted a fix request on github, but what you have to do is alter the jQuery Mobile source:

```
line 2159 of the alpha-3 release:
    $.mobile.changePage({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: $(this).serialize()
        },
        $(this).attr('data-transition'),  // this used to be *undefined* just like the next parameter
        undefined,
        true
    );
```

then you can just use `data-transition="fade"` in your form tag.

Comment: I think I've tried but it didn't work… For now, I removed ajax form submissions, not smooth but still better. Thx anyway !!

Answer (score 0):

I just use data-transition="none" and it seems to work. Maybe this is something that it was fixed. I am using 1.0a4.1